I can't add an image through object.create in Django
Good afternoon, I'm trying to insert an image into the database through object.create, but it's not being inserted in any way, everything else is inserted until the other image.
The image is being created that I have already tested, and is being loaded correctly as jpg.
But I'm not able to use it other than through the path, but I want it to be automatically inserted.
Insertion code I'm using:
stringRegisto = RegistoString.objects.create(string=string_registro,rostosDetectados=frame_io, ecra=estacao_trabalho.owner.photo)

way by path that is working:
stringRegisto = RegistoString.objects.create(string=string_registro, rostosDetectados="/rostos/frame_io.jpg", ecra=estacao_trabalho.owner.photo)

Views.py
    def run_recognition(self, request, frame):
    print("Executando reconhecimento facial...")
    
    rgb_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    # Encontra as localizações das faces no frame
    face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_frame)
    # Captura as caracteristicas faciais
    face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_frame, face_locations)

    face_names = []
    
    last_face_names = request.session.get('last_face_names', [])

    _, frame_encoded = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
    cv2.imwrite('frames/frame_io.jpg', frame)
    frame_io = ContentFile(frame_encoded.tobytes())


    if len(face_encodings) >= 2: # Se houver mais de um rosto no frame
        self.no_face_count = 0
        print("Dois rostos na imagem.")
        face_names = []

        for face_encoding in face_encodings:
            matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(self.known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
            name = "Unknown"
            if True in matches:
                first_match_index = matches.index(True)
                name = self.known_face_names[first_match_index]
            face_names.append(name)
            estacao_trabalho = EstacaoTrabalho.objects.get(uuid=self.uuid)

        # Ordena os nomes por ordem alfabética
        face_names.sort()
        
        print("Rostos reconhecidos:", ", ".join(face_names))

        estacao_owner_name = estacao_trabalho.owner.name
        
        # Verifica se houve mudança nos rostos reconhecidos

        if last_face_names == face_names:
            print("Rostos reconhecidos permanecem os mesmos, não criando registro.")
        else:
            # Verifica se o owner da EstacaoTrabalho tem um nome diferente dos rostos reconhecidos
            if estacao_trabalho.owner:  # Verifica se a estação de trabalho tem um proprietário
                # Se tiver um proprietário, atribui o nome do proprietário à variável estacao_owner_name
                print("Owner da estação de trabalho:", estacao_trabalho.owner.name)
                estacao_owner_name = estacao_trabalho.owner.name
            else:
                print("Estação de trabalho sem proprietário.")
                # Se não tiver um proprietário, atribui uma string vazia à variável estacao_owner_name
                estacao_owner_name = ""
                

            string_registro = f"{', '.join(face_names)} estão a visualizar a tela de {estacao_owner_name} na estacao {estacao_trabalho.name}"

            if not frame_io:
                raise ValueError("Nenhuma imagem fornecida")

            stringRegisto = RegistoString.objects.create(string=string_registro, rostosDetectados="/rostos/frame_io.jpg", ecra=estacao_trabalho.owner.photo)
            stringRegisto.save()

            print("Registro de string criado:", string_registro)
            request.session['last_face_names'] = face_names

Models
=======
class RegistoString(models.Model): #Tabela RegistosString
string = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
rostosDetectados = models.ImageField(upload_to='rostos/',null=True)
ecra = models.ImageField(upload_to='ecra/',null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.string


I already got the answer

I needed to define it in the "processar_facial_recognition" function and not in run_recognition
